# How to debug a jQuery application remotely on client's browser/OS/system?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have developed a web app (that uses jQuery) which works just fine for me but isn't working for one of my users. I've tried replicating the problem matching his browser/OS but it is of no use. The application works for me but not for him. He has tried with a lot of browsers: Chrome/Firefox/IE but it doesn't work in any for him. The only clue I have is that he says all his computers have German version of Windows installed. I wonder how that can be a cause.

Is there any tool that can dump JavaScript/HTML errors and email it to me? Or any script/extension for helping me remotely debug the issue? Help is appreciated.

The web app BTW is http://visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/ in case it helps.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&group=0

Try to fix the bugs in your HTML first

Comment: @Robert, actually the application is located at http://dev.visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/ so the bugs shouldn't affect this issue.

Answer (score 2):

If he's trying it in Chrome or Firefox, have him press Ctrl+Shift+J and that will bring up the Javascript Error Console. You can then ask him to copy-paste you whatever errors it might be having.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Copilot](https://www.copilot.com/) or some other remote-help solution. That way you will have complete control over the client's computer and I think that will be the easiest way to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your client to create a trace with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [FiddlerCap](http://www.fiddlercap.com/FiddlerCap/). Then you can replay the trace on your local system and see if the client received all the files or if certain http requests had errors.

Tracing instructions: [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/log_old.asp), [FiddlerCap](http://www.fiddlercap.com/FiddlerCap/)

If you're not familiar with Fiddler check out the [video](http://microsoftpdc.com/Sessions/CL25) or the [slides](http://ecn.channel9.msdn.com/o9/pdc09/ppt/CL25.pptx) for the *"Become a Web Debugging Virtuoso with Fiddler"* session from this year's PDC conference.

Hope this helps some.